Color gradiant beween red, white and green in javascript
I am trying to create a function like this:

function colorCell(current, min=-100, max=100) {
    current = Math.max(min, Math.min(current, max));

    return 'hsl(' + ((max + current) * 135 / (max - min)) + ", 100%, 50%)";
}


If current = 0, color should be white. If current is between 0 and min, color should move from light red to dark red. If color <= min, it should return same dark red.
Then it repeats the same thing between 0 and max but green color gradiant here.

How are you calling this and implementing it?

I think your main problem is that hsl is primarily for hues of color and also you're not changing the saturation or lightness. In order to get white I think you need to change the other values, not only hue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/blog/learn-css-hues-colors-hsl/   It might be helpful to consider other CSS color rules such as rgb or hex values. I made a jsfiddle to play around with the function you wrote: https://jsfiddle.net/j3pydev/gL90ryvm

e.g., a lightness of 100% will give you white

@j3py Entering -20 gives me yellowish color. I found a solution too

@CodePanda Yellow is a Hue. You need to adjust Lightness to get White, as told earlier by @j3py... PS: Easiest way to make a gradient between colours is to use RGB space. Use an interpolation algorithm (easy) to blend 2 points. First blend Red to White, then also blend White to Green. Given [255, 0, 0] just increase the g=0 and b=0 equally to get White (add lightness) so you end up with [255,255,255]. Next decrease r=255 and b=255 down to zero to get Green. Use divide to define number of steps (or pixels) when blending. Eg: reach_255 / in_30_steps = increment amount.

I created this function to solve my problem
function colorCell(current, min = -100, max = 100) {
    current = Math.max(min, Math.min(current, max));

    if (current < 0) {
        var percent = (1 - current / min) * 100;
        return `hwb(0deg ${percent}% 0%)`;
    }
    if (current > 0) {
        var percent = (1 - current / max) * 100;
        return `hwb(135deg ${percent}% 0%)`;
    }
}


